# Largest possible cost of a shortest path in which every edge's length is either -1, 0, or 1

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

I'm doing an online course in which I'm struggling with the following (multiple-choice) question:

> Suppose we run the FLoyd-Warshall algorithm on a directed graph $G =(V,E)$ in which every edge's length is either $-1,0,$ or $1$. Suppose further that $G$ is strongly connected, with at least one $u$-$v$ path for every pair $u,v$ of vertices. The graph $G$ may or may not have a negative-cost cycle. How large can the final entries $A[i,j,n]$ be, in absolute value? Choose the smallest number that is guaranteed to be a valid upper bound. (As usual, $n$ denotes $|V|$.) [WARNING: for this question, make sure you refer to the implementation of the Floyd-Warshall algorithm given in lecture, rather than to some alternative source.]
>
> 1. $+\infty$
> 2. $n^2$
> 3. $2^n$
> 4. $n-1$

I'm furthermore told that $n-1$ shouldn't be selected, with the hint "Experiment with graphs that have negative-cost cycles".

Here is the Floyd-Warshall algorithm as described in the lectures:

> Let $A$ be a 3-D array, indexed by $i,j,k$.
> Define the base cases:
> $$ A[i,j,0] = \begin{cases}0 & i = j \\ c_{i,j} & (i,j)\in E \\ +\infty & \text{else}\end{cases}$$
>
> ```
> For k = 1 to n
>     For i = 1 to n
>         For j = 1 to n
>             A[i,j,k] = min(A[i,j,k-1], A[i,k,k-1] + A[k,j,k-1])
> ```
>
> **Correctness**: From optimal substructure and induction, as usual.
>
> **Running time**: $O(1)$ per sub-problem, $O(n^3)$ total.

In the course's nomenclature, $n$ denotes the total number of vertices in the graph, so $A(i, j, n)$ is the shortest path from node $i$ to $j$ which may use all $n$ nodes.

As I understand it, a shortest path between any two nodes has at most $n - 1$ edges, so if the maximum cost of an edge is 1, I would expect the maximum cost of a shortest path to be $n - 1$. I don't see how the presence of negative-cost cycles could change this?

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; we don't like that. Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can use LaTeX) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: They give you a good hint: *try some inputs*.

Comment: In particular, try it with a graph containing a negative-weight cycle. I'm voting to leave this open, since you do explain your reasoning and it's not just a problem dump.

Comment: This question has been answered [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14839/running-floyd-warshall-algorithm-on-graph-with-negative-cost-cycle). The gist is that, for every iteration of the outer loop (i.e., for every increment of subproblem size) the shortest paths can be reduced by a factor of 2, thereby having exponential behavior. This is assuming a fully connected graph with all weights equal to -1.

Comment: +1 to @Raphael's comment. Every question ever posted by the OP are screenshots; clearly, some people are just plain lazy. I've edited two of them for better searchability.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Great, thanks! If any user keeps doing that after being asked not to, feel free to vote for closure and/or flag instead!

Answer (score 2):

> a shortest path between any two nodes has at most n - 1 edges

This is only true for simple paths *(paths with no repeat nodes)*. If there is a negative-cost cycle, you can take the cycle multiple times to get a shorter path.

Comment: Continueing that thought, there *no longer is* a shortest path.

Comment: I suppose that in the presence of negative cycles, `A[i, j, n]` no longer represents the shortest path length. The question essentially is what it _does_ represent, and in particular what its maximum value could be. In that regard I don't see how the presence of negative cycles could increase its value beyond that of _n_ - 1 that it would be if the graph had no negative cycles. Perhaps you can answer this more nuanced question?